# Where can I download DDESpy?

Tags: dde

I am looking for the old DDESpy tool.

Does anyone know where I could download it or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it: http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/06_w26/153525/DDESPY.exe.txt
(rename to exe, remove txt extension)

Answer (score 4):

It's part of Visual Studio 6, and isn't downloadable officially. You have to find a distribution of VS6.

[This MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/7c51e728-b6a5-4862-a436-8beae33a60d1) talks about replacing it with Spy++.